# Populate setters by looping an arraylist

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist

I am doing a project for college. 1 of the main problem that is stopping nearly all of my progress is to populate the setters with the arraylist content. The arraylist is of type object.
Here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Whisky {

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private int quantity;


    public Whisky(String nm, String desc, int quant) {
        this.name = nm;
        this.description = desc;
        this.quantity = quant;


        List<Object> WhiskyList = new ArrayList<Object>() ;
        WhiskyList.add("Balvenie");
        WhiskyList.add("triple cask 12.  Matured in the three most traditional types of cask – first-fill bourbon, refill bourbon and sherry");
        WhiskyList.add(10);
        WhiskyList.add("Glenfiddich");
        WhiskyList.add("Reserve Cask. This Whisky has been matured exclusively in Spanish sherry casks");
        WhiskyList.add(10);
        WhiskyList.add("Laphroig");
        WhiskyList.add("Laphroig Four Oak. Matured in four different types of cask: ex-bourbon barrels, small quarter casks, virgin American oak barrels and European oak hogsheads.");
        WhiskyList.add(10);

   }   


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

     public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity= quant;
    }
}
```

So basically what I am trying to do is to run a for loop that goes through the arraylist.size() and for each "step" it takes, it places the content into the right setter. Is that possible?

Comment: This is a strange thing to want to do. What are the actual requirements of the project you're trying to implement?

Comment: basically to create a GUI application that uses RMI +it HAS to use arraylist. So basically I though it be the easiest and quickest way to create an arraylist, populate setters and in the next class just use the getters.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to set up an initial list of Whisky instances.  There are many ways to do this.  Here is one that uses a static List and populates it with a static method (runs once at class load time.)

```
public class Whisky {

  public static final List<Whisky> WhiskyList = new ArrayList<Whisky>();

  static {
    WhiskyList.add(new Whisky("Balvenie",
                              "triple cask 12.  Matured in the three most traditional types of cask – first-fill bourbon, refill bourbon and sherry",
                              10));
    WhiskyList.add(new Whisky("Glenfiddich",
                              "Reserve Cask. This Whisky has been matured exclusively in Spanish sherry casks",
                              10));
    WhiskyList.add(new Whisky("Laphroig",
                              "Laphroig Four Oak. Matured in four different types of cask: ex-bourbon barrels, small quarter casks, virgin American oak barrels and European oak hogsheads.",
                              10));
  }

  private String name;
  private String description;
  private int quantity;

  public Whisky(String nm, String desc, int quant) {
    this.name = nm;
    this.description = desc;
    this.quantity = quant;
  }

  // finish with getters and settings
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, `WhiskeyList` can be declared and used in a `main()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of a your class should only initialize the fields of the class. Most likely the `WhiskeyList` variable should go in a `main()` method. But before you do that, I suggest writing a `main()` that just creates a single `Whiskey` instance.

Comment: Right. So You are saying to put the WhiskyList into the main class. What if for example I had to declare 25 different whisky. Is there a better, more "efficient" way of doing it than just having an arraylist and pass it on to the setters?

Comment: @CoDVideosPL An ArrayList to store multiple instances of the `Whiskey` class have nothing to do with the individual setters on those instances. You only pass the value that you are setting to the setters, such as the name, not a whole list of `Whiskey` objects.